# Intellisense for lambda expressions / functional programming. Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, functional-programming, intellisense

In visual studio, when we write some code, it gives me an intellisense if that can be written as a lambda expression. Does eclipse have any such intellisense built in for functional programming? That makes one learn quickly and get habituated to use them in day-in and day-out.

Comment: I don't think so. IntelliJ does though.

Comment: Although it is not built-in but a plugin in the marketplace, SonarLint is providing hints about to use lambda if appropriate. I don't know if it marks all kind of possibilities when to use lambdas but I think it is a nice tool in general.